# How is sys.stdin buffered in Python?

Tags: python, buffer, stdin

I am developing a script that accepts log output from Apache. My solution is as follows:

```
while True:
        log_line = sys.stdin.readline()

        while(log_line == ""): # wait for new line 
            time.sleep(2)
            log_line = sys.stdin.readline() # buffer issue? 

        # process the line here
```

The problem is that while observing the differences between the apache log and the log of lines processed by my script, I noticed that my program is missing some lines. I expect this must have something to do with the lines being dropped/overwritten during the timing delay, but I am unable to find in depth information about how Python's std.in is buffered.

My assumption was that if multiple lines are sent to std.in during the time.sleep(2), they will be buffered and eventually accessible via subsequent sys.stdin.readline() calls. Is this not correct?

Comment: stdin buffering is mostly determined by external factors, not by Python itself.

Comment: If you're missing lines in the middle, buffering is unlikely to be the cause of your problem. Maybe your script is buggy, or maybe the lines you're thinking of were never sent to your script's stdin in the first place. If you're experiencing delays with receiving lines, that could be buffering.

Comment: It seems unlikely it would be any of the processing as every line that is read is written to my debug file. For some reason it's just not reading all of the lines sent to stdin. Maybe it's an issue with Apache.